# Assign property value using an anonymous function

Tags: php, oop

My class is like this:

```
<?php

class ExampleClass{

    private $example_property = false;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->example_property = function() {
            $this->example_property = 1;
            return $this->example_property;
        };
    }

    public function get_example_property(){
        return $this->example_property; 
    }
}

$example = new ExampleClass();
echo $example->get_example_property();
```

Property `$example_property` must be `false` until you call it, then, the first time it is called, I want to assign `1` to it. What's wrong with my code?

Error: `Error Object of class Closure could not be converted to string on line number 20`.

Comment: What language are you coming from? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `$this->example_property` is already a closure when `ExampleClass` is instantiate, and when you get it with `get_example_property` you need to call it first.

Comment: Just add `if(!$this->example_property){$this->example_property=1}` to the function `get_example_property `. I think, there's no need to use a closure.

Comment: @akrys thank you but I don't like this solution.

Comment: **What are you actually trying to do?**

Comment: @Federkun I'm trying to initialize a huge propery only if child class will need it, and I don't like that child class will have to call a method to initialize $example_property.

Comment: then you have a completely different question; can you re-write it?

Comment: @Federkun you mean if I can rethink the class?

Comment: no, your question. You basically want use this: https://github.com/Ocramius/LazyProperty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just tried to play a little bit with your code.

To make it possible, you'll have to find out, whether your variable is a function (defined in your `__construct`) or the number set by this function

```
<?php

class ExampleClass{

    private $example_property = false;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->example_property = function() {
            $this->example_property = 1;
            return $this->example_property;
        };
    }

    public function get_example_property(){
        $func = $this->example_property;
        if(is_object($func) && get_class($func)=='Closure'){
            return $func();
        }
        return $func;
    }
}

$example = new ExampleClass();
echo $example->get_example_property(); //returning 1
echo $example->get_example_property(); //returning 1 again
```

But anyway, I don't see any sense in doing this.

The typical solution would be something like this:

```
class ExampleClass{

    private $example_property = false;

    public function __construct(){
        //usually initializing properties goes here.
        //$this->example_property = 1;
    }

    public function get_example_property(){
        // I think you want a value to be initialzed only if needed.
        // so then it can go here.
        if(!$this->example_property) {
            $this->example_property = 1; //initialize it, if needed
        }
        return $this->example_property;
    }
}

$example = new ExampleClass();
echo $example->get_example_property(); //returning 1
echo $example->get_example_property(); //returning 1 again
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use your second solution because the first solution is very ugly.

Comment: That was, what I tried to express in my first comment ;-)